# Is it possible to read an SRML error message in Substrate UI, when a transaction fails?

Tags: substrate

I am not sure of the behaviour of error messages in Substrate runtimes in relation to Substrate UI, and if they inherently cause a transaction failure or not.

For example in the `democracy` SRML I see the following line:

```
ensure!(!<Cancellations<T>>::exists(h), "cannot cancel the same proposal twice");
```

Which presumably is a macro that ensures that the transaction fails or stops processing if the `h` (the proposal hash) already exists. There is clearly a message associated with this error.

Am I right to assume that the transaction fails (without the rest of the SRML code being executed) when this test fails?

If so, how do I detect the failure in Substrate UI, and possibly see the message itself?

If not, then presumably some further code is necessary in the runtime module which explicitly creates an error. I have seen `Err()` - but not in conjunction with `ensure!()`

Comment: FYI all the error handling in Substrate is likely to change soon: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/2880

Probably best to ask your question after this is merged in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/3433 is merged, the `ExtrinsicFailed` event now includes a `DispatchError`, which will provide additional error code.

There isn't much documentations available so I will just use `system` module as example.

First you need to `decl_error`, note the error variants can only be simple C like enum

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/5420de3face1349a97eb954ae71c5b0b940c31de/srml/system/src/lib.rs#L334

```
decl_error! {
    /// Error for the System module
    pub enum Error {
        BadSignature,
        BlockFull,
        RequireSignedOrigin,
        RequireRootOrigin,
        RequireNoOrigin,
    }
}
```

Then you need to associate the declared `Error` type
https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/5420de3face1349a97eb954ae71c5b0b940c31de/srml/system/src/lib.rs#L253

```
decl_module! {
    pub struct Module<T: Trait> for enum Call where origin: T::Origin {
        type Error = Error;
```

Then you can just return your `Error` in dispatch calls when things failed

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/5420de3face1349a97eb954ae71c5b0b940c31de/srml/system/src/lib.rs#L543

```
pub fn ensure_root<OuterOrigin, AccountId>(o: OuterOrigin) -> Result<(), Error>
    where OuterOrigin: Into<Result<RawOrigin<AccountId>, OuterOrigin>>
{
    match o.into() {
        Ok(RawOrigin::Root) => Ok(()),
        _ => Err(Error::RequireRootOrigin),
    }
}
```

Right now you will only able to see a two numbers, module index and error code from JS side. Later there could be support to include the error details in metadata so that frontend will be able to provide a better response.

Related issue:
https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/2954

Comment: This is a great explanation! well written.

Answer (score 0):

The `ensure!` macro is expaneded as:

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! fail {
    ( $y:expr ) => {{
        return Err($y);
    }}
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! ensure {
    ( $x:expr, $y:expr ) => {{
        if !$x {
            $crate::fail!($y);
        }
    }}
}
```

So basically, it's just a quicker way to return `Err`. At 1.0, the error msg will only be printed to stdout(at least what I've tested so far), doesn't know if it'll be included in blockchain in the future(so can be viewed in substrate ui)..

Comment: Could you expand on what the UI needs to do to recognise that there has been an error?

Comment: I think you need to check the status of the extrinsic. The Polkadot UI shows "extrinsic failed" pop up in these situations.

Comment: @T9b I don't think it's currently possible... but you might use `Event` instead.